# How to get image URL within HTML tags?

Tags: php, android, html

I need to get proper image for each article. Every single image is saved among different HTML tags in different rows in database. So how should I get img URL with PHP code?

```
 <p><img src="images/akhbar/5/q103.jpg" alt="q103" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" height="315" width="675" /></p>
<p> Who is Sara Bareilles on Sing Off</p>
```

[image: image urls are saved in introtext row in my database]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A regex is probably the wrong solution here. Assuming you have only one image per row in your highlighted column, I would wrap each one in an HTML document, and then you parse it with an HTML parser.

Comment: The image is not a very good way to show what you have though, since images are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers or search engines. Would you replace it with a few samples of HTML **in text format**? Formatting tools are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers.i could solve my problem with this code.hope help other guys.

```
$text = $row["your html text from database row"]; 
preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $text, $img);
            $pics=$img[1];
```

output is ($pics)= ( images/akhbar/5/q103.jpg  )

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not good at regex-ing but I did give it a try. Check this if it works.

```
$str="<p><img src='sfd;lfjnglsmsfd.jpg' />"; //This is where you pass that column value
$del="src=";
$pos=strpos($str, $del);
$important=substr($str, $pos+strlen($del), strlen($str)-1);
$pos2=strpos($important, ".jpg");
$final = substr($important, 0, $pos2);
$final = str_replace("'", "", $final);
return $url = $final.".jpg";
```